# Define a unbounded functional on C00 ⊂ l 2 . Justify your answer

Tags: unbounded-operators

I know that Not possessing both an upper and a lower bound. So for all positive real values V there is a value of the independent variable x for which |f(x)|>V. For example, f (x)=x 2 is unbounded because f (x)≥0 but f(x) → ∞ as x → ±∞, i.e. it is bounded below but not above, while f(x)=x 3 has neither upper nor lower bound.

How do i find unbounded function for the above question

Comment: You probably need to tell us what you mean by Coo and l2.

Comment: @bubba C00 : Space of all eventually constant sequences converging to 0. and l2 is Space of all square summable sequences with 2 − norm.